# How can I introduce a copied variable as mutable in a if-let statement?

Tags: rust, mutable

I have a `HashMap<i8, i8>` which could contain cycles:

```
let mut x: HashMap<i8, i8> = HashMap::new();
x.insert(1, 6);
x.insert(3, 5);
x.insert(5, 1);
```

To get the final value for `3`, it should first lookup `x[3]`, then `x[5]` and finally `x[1]` which should yield `6`. I decided to use a `while let` loop:

```
let mut y = x[&3]; // y: i8
while let Some(&z) = x.get(&y) {
    y = z;
}

println!("{}", y);

x.insert(0, 0);
```

This works fine, but it would `panic!` if `3` is not in the map. As I don't want to do anything about the `None` case, I want to use a `if let` (similar to the `while let` used).

I have tried some notations:

1. `if let Some(&y) = x.get(&3)`: copies the value, but y is immutable (`y: i8`)
2. `if let Some(mut y) = x.get(&3)`: y is mutable, but the value is borrowed (`mut y: &i8`)
3. `if let mut Some(&y) = x.get(&3)`: my target: mutable copy, but invalid syntax (`mut y: i8`)

(All variants are available at [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8b4c4dbc59ac6293f1c65b260338c63f&version=stable&backtrace=0), but you need to comment out the third try, as it is invalid syntax)

I would not argue about the second variant, but I need to insert values into my map in the body of the `if let`. As the map remains borrowed, I can't insert anymore. All I would need is that the value in `Some(y)` is copied, and `y` is mutable, so that the borrow checker is satisfied and I can do my recursive lookups.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach #1 is a perfectly correct match, you just need to make the `y` variable mutable. One possibility is to convert `Option<&i8>` to `Option<i8>`, enabling the use of `mut y` in the pattern. For example, `Option::map` can dereference the value:

```
if let Some(mut y) = x.get(&3).map(|ref| *ref) {
```

Since `Copy` implies (cheap) `Clone`, you can express the same using `Option::cloned()`:

```
if let Some(mut y) = x.get(&3).cloned() {
```

As of Rust 1.35, you can use `Option::copied()`, which is guaranteed to just copy the value (and fails to compile if the value is not `Copy`):

```
if let Some(mut y) = x.get(&3).copied() {
```

Another possibility is to leave your approach #1 as-is, but correct it simply by introducing a separate mutable variable inside the `if let` block:

```
if let Some(&y) = x.get(&3) {
    let mut y = y;
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code basically works:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut x: HashMap<i8, i8> = HashMap::new();
    x.insert(1, 6);
    x.insert(3, 5);
    x.insert(5, 1);

    let mut key = 3;
    while let Some(&z) = x.get(&key) {
        key = z;
    }

    println!("{}", key);

    x.insert(key, 0);
}
```

Here, `key` is left as the last key that did not match.

Comment: Even it is cleaner removing the `ìf let`, the `if` is necessary in my specific use-case.